# modifying jquery-ui accordian to display tickers

Tags: jquery-ui

want to modify the original Accordian from jquery-ui :

[image: original Accordian]

to look something like:

[image: modified Accordian]

but have no idea where to start.....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At a high level, you have two puzzles.  The first is dynamically changing the content of your accordion header and the second is "ticking ..." that content.

For the first, the first, you can find the heading that contains the accordion text with:

```
$("#myAccordion").find(".ui-accordion-header")
```

You can then dynamically set the text of that element which will change the text of your accordion.

For the ticker, I'd suggest creating a timer and when the timer fires, change the text of the accordion to be your new text.

Comment: thank you. I am needing helpful hints. I am already looking around for some json feeds, like openweather. by the way i do not know who is the guy who is downgrading this Q an A.

Comment: Don't worry about it ... when I vote, I make it a point to always explain my reasoning.  I think if you google around you may find some existing ticker widgets.  I think I saw some on a jQuery plugin exchange.